# C++11::parentheses after the type name make a difference with new

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, new-operator, default-constructor

[Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

**How it's different in C++11?**

And suppose we use initializer list, then how it's different?

```
TestWidget::TestWidget(): QWidget(parent)
, m_BoxWidget(new BoxWidget())
{
}
```

vs

```
TestWidget::TestWidget(): QWidget(parent)
, m_BoxWidget(new BoxWidget)
{
}
```

My BoxWidget class has constructor defined by me where I initialize the box's coordinates.

Comment: The semantics of e.g. `new BoxWidget()` versus `new BoxWidget` haven't changed in C++11 (or later). And it doesn't matter where you do it, it's still the same.

Comment: Helpful comment.